# How to use chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow() in non-interactive mode?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, service-worker

I am using chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow() method to generate access token in my chrome extension, but it gives sign-in window every time browser reopens. How can I use it it in non-interactive mode? when interactive property is set to false it gives error: "user interaction required."
Following is my code:

```
async function getAuthToken() {
    var auth_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?";
    var redirect_url = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL(); 

    var auth_params = {
      client_id: myClientID,
      redirect_uri: redirect_url,
      response_type: "token",
      
      scope: [
        //my scopes
      ].join(" "),
    };

    const url = new URLSearchParams(Object.entries(auth_params));
    url.toString();
    auth_url += url;

    const responseUrl = chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
      url: auth_url,
      interactive: true,
     
    });
    
    console.log(responseUrl);
}
```

Comment: I am new to this myself and have been looking at this [example](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/identify_user/#auth-url). I changed 'authUrl.searchParams.set('prompt', 'consent');' to 'authUrl.searchParams.set('prompt', 'none');`. I think this is what you are looking for?